# VS2010 code analysis strange array limit error

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

I have a class defined like this:

```
#include <cassert>

class Vector
{
     double v[2];

     double operator()(int i) const
     {
         assert(i>=0 && i<2);
         return this->v[i];
     }
};
```

when running the VS2010 code analysis tool, a warning is thrown on array access:

```
warning C6385: Invalid data: accessing 'this->v', the readable size is '16' bytes, but '-16' bytes might be read
```

but it seems perfectly valid to me, as the assert should prevent any negative value. What is happening?

---

Edit: it seems that code analysis does not correctly handle asserts:

```
assert(i<2)
```

generates

```
warning C6385: Invalid data: accessing 'this->v', the readable size is '16' bytes, but '24' bytes might be read
```

while

```
assert(i>=0)
```

generates

```
warning C6385: Invalid data: accessing 'this->v', the readable size is '16' bytes, but '-16' bytes might be read
```

Replacing the asserts with ifs removes the problem.

Comment: What happens if instead of `assert` you have an `if`-statement?

Comment: Dan: it works correctly. Could this mean that the tool is just mishandling the assert()?

Comment: If you are interested in static analysis tools at the same time try to PVS-Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite an old one, but I wanted to post my findings on it:

Replacing the int with a size_t fixes it because an int can be < 0, and so you rightfully get the analysis error.

To fix it either change it to size_t, or unsigned int.

Static analysis does not take asserts into account, which is why the if works, but assert doesn't. if you want to surpress the warning you can add:

`_analysis_assume(i>0 && i < MY_MAX_VALUE)`

This will tell the analyzer which values to expect for i.

Answer (score 1):

The analyzer probably isn't taking the `assert` into account when it looks at the `return this->v[i];`.

To fix it, use types instead of asserts to enforce a positive index:

```
class Vector { 
    double v[2];
public:
    double operator()(size_t i) const { 
        assert(i<2);
        return v[i];
    }
};
```

As an aside, using `this->whatever` (except when truly necessary, which is *rare* and only in templates anyway) makes you look clueless.

Comment: Even changing to size_t, the assert seems not to be considered correctly: see my expanded question for the case of assert(i<2).